# Change text color on select

Tags: android

I am trying to change the text color of text in the textView on Select. I have tried many examples but none of them are working.
Here is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/goal"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/goalText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="63dp"
            android:background="@drawable/white_border_rounded"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:layout_margin="18dp"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/goal1"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="21sp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/goalText2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="63dp"
                android:background="@drawable/white_border_rounded"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:layout_margin="18dp"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/goal2"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="21sp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/goalText3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="63dp"
                android:background="@drawable/white_border_rounded"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:layout_margin="18dp"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/goal3"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="21sp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/goalText4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="63dp"
                android:background="@drawable/white_border_rounded"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:layout_margin="18dp"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/goal4"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="21sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my white_border_rounded:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false" >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
        <corners android:radius="50dip" />
        <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/white" />
    </shape>

</item>
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="false" android:color="#444">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
        <corners android:radius="50dip" />
        <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/white" />
        <solid android:color="#fff"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true" android:color="#444">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
        <corners android:radius="50dip" />
        <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/white" />
        <solid android:color="#fff"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item >
    <shape android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="true" android:color="#444">
        <corners android:radius="50dip" />
        <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/white" />
        <solid android:color="#fff"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Below is my java file:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.goalText1:
            changeViewBackground(true,false,false,false);
            goal_selection = mGoal1.getText().toString();
            break;

        case R.id.goalText2:
            changeViewBackground(false,true,false,false);
            goal_selection = mGoal2.getText().toString();
            break;

        case R.id.goalText3:
            changeViewBackground(false,false,true,false);
            goal_selection = mGoal3.getText().toString();
            break;

        case R.id.goalText4:
            changeViewBackground(false,false,false,true);
            goal_selection = mGoal4.getText().toString();
            break;

        case R.id.btnGoal:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, fiteness_level_selection.class);
```

}

```
 private void changeViewBackground(boolean view1,boolean view2,boolean
        view3,boolean view4) {
    mGoal1.setSelected(view1);
    mGoal2.setSelected(view2);
    mGoal3.setSelected(view3);
    mGoal4.setSelected(view4);

}
```

I want when a user select any textView its text color should change to black and when it selects other textview then previous text color should change back to original color i.e white.

Comment: try this for others :- mGoal1.setBackgroundColor(getResources.getColor(R.color.Red));

Comment: @VishalPatoliya I want to change the text color> I tried this also but this doesn't work for me.

Comment: mGoal1.setTextColor(getResources.getColor(R.color.Red));

Answer (score 0):

I would create a loop which would go through all these TextViews.And change their color depening on their Tags. Firstly, I would put all of the TextViews into an ArrayList, and when any of them are clicked, I would call a method that would set the text color in them all. I will write the code in a few minutes and post it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
List<TextView> textViewList = new ArrayList<TextView>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    TextView mGoal1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.goalText1); mGoal1.setTag("no");
    TextView mGoal2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.goalText2);mGoal2.setTag("no");
    TextView mGoal3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.goalText3);mGoal3.setTag("no");


    textViewList.add(mGoal1);
    textViewList.add(mGoal2);
    textViewList.add(mGoal3);

    mGoal1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           view.setTag("yes");
            ChangeColor();
        }
    });
    mGoal2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            view.setTag("yes");
            ChangeColor();
        }
    });
    mGoal3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            view.setTag("yes");
            ChangeColor();
        }
    });

}
void ChangeColor(){


        for (int i =0;i<textViewList.size();i++)
        {
            if (textViewList.get(i).getTag().equals("yes")){
                textViewList.get(i).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                textViewList.get(i).setTag("no");
            }
            else textViewList.get(i).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

        }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

To change colour of a `TextView` you need to do the following.

```
TextView.onClickListener() {
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                TextView text = (TextView)view;
                text.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
            }
        });
```

Comment: I tried this also but when i select another text view the previous textcolor is still set to black. What I want is only the selected textView textcolor should be black.